# Sorting a linkedList by the value of the object

Tags: java, linked-list

For an assignment, I've been tasked to create a priority based support ticket system which contains the user's Name, ID, Handler and Priority however ticket's with higher priority are placed first in the list to be dealt with.

I have three classes. 
Main: where I add/delete and change ticket priority.
TicketSystem: Contains the constructor for the ticket alongside getters and setter methods
LinkedList: Has insert, delete printList and should have sortList

So far I've determined the algorithm needs to be bubblesort as Priority is an int value but I'm not too sure how to receive the value for priority and then sort it.

```
public class TicketSystem {
private  String handler;
private  int priority;
private  String iD;
private  String creator;

public TicketSystem() {

}


public String getHandler ( ) {
    return handler;
}

public int getPriority () {
    return priority; 
}

public String getID () {
    return iD;
}
public String creator () {
    return creator; 
}

public void setID (String i)  {

    this.iD = i; 

}
public void setHandler (String h) {
    this.handler =  h; 
}
public void setPriority (int p ) {
this.priority = p; 
}

public String setCreator (String c) {
return this.creator = c;
}



public void addTicket( String h, int p, String c, String iD) {
    this.handler = h;
this.priority = p;
this.iD = iD; 
this.creator = c;
}




@Override
public String toString() {
   String output = "";
   output += "Handler: " + handler +", ";
   output += "Priority: " + priority + ", ";
   output += "Creator: "  + creator + ", ";
   output += "ID: " + iD + " ";
   return output;

}




}




 public class LinkedList {                                 
 private Node head;
 public LinkedList(TicketSystem ticket) {          
 head = new Node();                            
 head.ticket = ticket;                            
 head.link = null;                              
 }


   public boolean insertItem(TicketSystem ticket) { 
   Node n = new Node();                          
   Node new_node;
   new_node = head;                            
   while (new_node.link != null) {             
        new_node = new_node.link;                
   }
   n.ticket = ticket;                          
   n.link = null;                                
   new_node.link = n;                            
   return true; 

  }

   public void printList() {                   
   Node z = head;                         
   while (z!= null) {                           
       System.out.println(z.ticket.toString());
       z = z.link;
   }
 }

  public boolean deleteItem(TicketSystem ticket) { 
   if(ticket.equals(head.ticket)) {
       head = head.link;   
       return true; 
   } else {
       Node prevNode = head;         
       Node curNode = head.link;    
       while(curNode != null && !(curNode.ticket == ticket)) {
               prevNode = curNode;  
               curNode = curNode.link;  

       }
       if(curNode != null) {  
           prevNode.link = curNode.link;
           return true;
       } else {
           return false; 
       }
     }

  }

  /* sort list */

  public void sortList() {
   TicketSystem ts = new TicketSystem();
   }
   class Node {                                  
     private TicketSystem ticket;    
     private Node link;   
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you're looking for help with your `LinkedList` class, we'll need to see your `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Btw, `ticket's with higher priority are placed first` That is called a Priority Queue.

Comment: I've added in the linked list but should I research into Priority Queue if that's the solution? First time I've heard about it. Do you mind explaining how I could perhaps incorporate that element into my program?

Comment: @markspace is correct. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html and you will get all the details. You can find examples too on various sites

Usually this happens with either students or new programmers that they don't know various ready made APIs... so I would suggest to search for keywords like in this case "priority and sorted collection" or something on that terms... that should give you options available in APIs... this is for next problem though

Comment: Thank you so much, however my lecturer instructed us not to use pre-built libraries excluding array-list (though discouraged). Many of the student's I work with have been using Linked List and whilst a majority weren't able to add in a sort mechanism I know a few who did. I've got a way of adding it in but only within the Main method which seems impractical to me so I'm trying to find a way of doing it within the linked list. However, from what I'm getting at I'll need to switch data structures from Linked List to Priority Queue